# SMTP credentials for one server on another server - how does it work?

Tags: email, postfix, email-server, port, dovecot

I have two VPS on DigitalOcean: example.com for my web page and mail.example.com as an email server.

On mail.example.com I can successfully send and receive emails using terminal or a Roundcube web interface.
I use Postfix and Dovecot, and the mail user username and password is the same as those of a Unix user.

My problem is that example.com cannot send out emails at all, for example for user registrations.
I am trying with the SMTP credentials for my mail.example.com, without luck.

So I am trying to understand how this all works. If I want to use the SMTP credentials of mail.example.com
on example.com, do I need to open the mail ports on example.com and use Postfix and Dovecot on it to relay?
Or is this not necessary and the error is somewhere to be found on mail.example.com?

I have been struggling with this for a week now, so I would really appreciate any sort of guidance here.

Comment: This is a really broad request. You haven’t really provided any troubleshooting steps you followed to narrow this problem down and you leave it open for us to have to guess any number of different things that could be wrong. The obvious thing is have you made sure port 25 is reachable on the mail server? Have you confirmed the SMTP service is working and accepting those credentials in anyway? Have you looked at any logs? That last thing seems obvious if you are trying to troubleshoot the issue. If you want to know what is wrong read the logs.

Comment: `My problem is that example.com cannot send out emails at all, for example for user registrations. I am trying with the SMTP credentials for my mail.example.com, without luck.` - You've left out some very important details about HOW the web server is trying to send email. Is the web server trying to establish an SMTP session to the mail server? If so, how?

Comment: @Appleoddity, thank you for the feedback. All ports are reachable on the mail server, I assume, as I can send and receive mail perfectly fine using the terminal directly or the web interface. The SMTP credentials are accepted by the web interface when I log in, so, again I am assuming this means that it works. I will look at the logs more closely on mail.example.com tomorrow.

Comment: @joeqwerty, thank you for pointing that out. I actually did that on purpose, as I am more curious about the mechanisms than the nitty-gritty. To rephrase my question a bit: Does example.com have to communicate with mail.example.com through mail ports? Do I need to open mail ports on example.com as well? And to answer your question, I am using 'WP Mail SMTP', a plugin for Wordpress, to test (and fail) the SMTP connection. I use TLS and port 587, but I have tried all other ports as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you tested sending emails via terminal or the Roundcube web interface, was that directly on the mail server vps?  If so, then it wouldn't necessarily mean the inbound ports of the mail server are enabled (which is what your webserver) would be trying to connect over.

1. I recommend you test and connect to SMTP mail server account with any email client (gmail, Outlook) before trying to connect with Wordpress on the webserver. This will allow you to verify the mail server itself is setup for inbound SMTP connections.
2. Then, try connecting via Wordpress' WP Mail SMTP plugin interface.

   - If that fails, your webserver may have outbound ports for SMTP blocked/disabled. [By default (as of 2015)](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/questions/why-my-server-can-t-connect-to-gmail-smtp), Digital Ocean has an initial SMTP block on new VPS accounts created in certain contexts. If you file a support ticket (https://cloud.digitalocean.com/support) the team should be able to lift that for you after some manual account verification.
   - If after DO has confirmed the ports are open for SMTP, check that the IP of the webserver itself isn't blacklisted.

Comment: "This will allow you to verify the mail server itself is setup for inbound SMTP connections." I accepted your answer because of this sentence. I discovered I had to validate the sending address used in the Wordpress plugin with the SMTP server. I did this using smtpd_sender_login_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/controlled_envelope_senders and entered the sending address and owner (Unix username) in controlled_envelope_senders.